# Can I set up Lync account on built-in mail client?

Tags: applications, email

Is it possible to setup Lync into built-in mail client application?
How?

Comment: Not sure about in-built email client. But, have you tried using the Microsoft's [Lync 2013](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.lync15) app for android? Also Please add you device details and Android version info by [editing](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/119131/edit) your question.

Comment: @Lucky: Yes, I've tried  _Microsoft's Lync 2013_ app for android. It consumes too much battery power, that is why I want to configure it in my built-in e-mail client. There is no need to **add device details and Android version info** as this can be useful to any user who is using _Microsoft's Lync 2013 app_ for Android.

Comment: Information about your device is actually useful here because not all devices have the same "built-in" email application. It varies from one manufacturer to another, as do the supported features. In this case, I think the answer is "no" for all of them (but I could be wrong).